# Phonegap : get absolute path of a folder in the app's root folder

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-plugins

How to get absolute path of a folder in the app's root folder?

I am using [MobileChromeApps zip PhoneGap](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip) plugin to unzip files. I want to unzip the files into a folder inside the app's root folder.

How can I achieve this?

So far I've used the following code to unzip the file :

`zip.unzip("http://10.100.100.100/test.zip", **<DESTINATION_UNZIP_PATH>**, callBack);`

I want to know what can I enter in DESTINATION_UNZIP_PATH to extract the files in my app's root folder.

Comment: What do you consider to be the apps root folder?

Comment: my "www" folder in the phonegap project/build. i want to extract the files into the "www/test" folder inside the root folder

Comment: `inside the root folder` And where is the root folder was the question.

Comment: `in the phonegap project/build.` Why are you talking about a folder in the IDE? You will not download to some folder in the IDE would you? You would do that on the device. Did you investigate where on the device the www folder is placed?

Comment: I dont know where on the device is the root folder. I found that calling `window.location.href` returns "file:///android_asset/www/index.html", so this might be the root folder path. However, I couldnt get the folders inside it and unzip the files into it. How to do this?

Comment: I don't know. In a normal app with a WebView the WebView could load pages from assets in (nearly) such a way. But (normal) apps cannot add files to the assets folder as the assets folder is not a folder on the filesystem but some virtual thing in the apk.

Comment: If you look in https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip/blob/master/tests/tests.js you see that `fs.root.getDirectory('zipOutput', {create: true}, function(fileEntry)` is used.

Comment: OH! then is there a way where i can place the files in a location related to the app? Because, the apps accesses the image, audio, and other files using relative path with respect to root files. I've coded the stuff like this `<img src='/images/img.png'/>`

Comment: Pleas try. I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your help @greenapps, I will let u know once, i get a solution to this.